# IF/ELSE Statement in a DataFrame Based On Two Columns

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have created a DataFrame that has multiple columns and I need to create a new column based on conditions from two other columns. In this case, if the race is Caucasian and the ethnicity is Hispanic then I want to return Hispanic. The "ELSE" is whatever else does not meet those two conditions. I thought using a ...apply(lamba x ...) but I'm not sure if x can be expanded to more than one column.

```
cdc_data = pd.read_csv("../Project_1/cdc_data.csv")

cdc_df = pd.DataFrame(cdc_data)
cdc_df.columns
cdc_df = cdc_df[['case_month', 'res_state', 'res_county', 'age_group', 'sex', 'race', 'ethnicity', 'current_status']]
cdc_df = cdc_df.rename(columns={
    'case_month': 'Year-Month',
    'res_state': 'State',
    'res_county': 'County',
    'age_group': 'Age Group',
    'race': 'Race',
    'sex': 'Sex',
    'ethnicity': 'Ethnicity',
    'current_status': 'Infection Status'
})
# Drop "Unkown" race from dataset
cdc_df = cdc_df.loc[cdc_df['Race']!= 'Unknown',:]
cdc_df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow to the rescue:

```
cdc_df['Race2'] = np.where(np.logical_and(cdc_df['Race'] == 'Caucasian', cdc_df['Ethnicity'] == 'Hispanic/Latino'), 'Hispanic', cdc_df['Race'])
```